# Viewmodel containing UserControl - UserControl properties resetting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a main window viewmodel that is creating an instance of the usercontrol, and in a specific function, setting a property of the usercontrol via code i.e.

```
        // Set Button Width Height
        var potentialHeight = (SelectorUCViewModel.GridHeight / 
            SelectorUCViewModel.ColumnCount) - (SelectorUCViewModel.ButtonMarginToUse * 2);
        var potentialWidth = (SelectorUCViewModel.GridWidth / 
            SelectorUCViewModel.RowCount) - (SelectorUCViewModel.ButtonMarginToUse * 2);
        SelectorUCViewModel.ButtonHeightWidth = (potentialHeight < potentialWidth) ? potentialHeight : potentialWidth;
```

When this is called, the properties in the usercontrol change (you can see the setter is called). However, on the UI it looks like nothing has happened (margin is not there... toggle buttons are not there...)

I don't understand why....

An extract of XAML of my viewmodel has the following:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <views:SelectorUC x:Name="UC" DataContext="{Binding SelectorUCViewModel}" />
                            <Border DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="160" Margin="10 0 10 0">
                             <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Then the UserControl has the following XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="SelectorUC"
             x:Name="UC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Selector"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MouseDown="MainGrid_MouseDown" MouseUp="MainGrid_MouseUp" MouseMove="MainGrid_MouseMove" Background="Transparent" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      MinWidth="{Binding GridWidth}" Height="{Binding GridHeight}">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="objItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCompositeCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grid" Grid.Row="1" 
                                                 Width="{Binding MinWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" 
                                                 Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainGrid}"
                                                 GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                                                 GridHelper.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ObjA}">
                    <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
                                                        Tag="{Binding Id}"
                                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                        Height="{Binding Path=ButtonHeightWidth, ElementName=UC}"
                                                        Width="{Binding Path=ButtonHeightWidth, ElementName=UC}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                        Margin="{Binding Path=ButtonMarginToUse, ElementName=UC}"
                                                        Padding="2"
                                                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
                                                        MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource ObjButton}">
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GridLabeller}">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}" Style="{StaticResource GridHeaders}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="selectionBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SecondaryThemeColour}" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the properties that are resetting in the UC class

```
    private int buttonHeightWidth;
    public int ButtonHeightWidth
    {
        get { return buttonHeightWidth; }
        set
        {
            buttonHeightWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonHeightWidth));
        }
    }

    private int buttonMarginToUse = 2;
    public int ButtonMarginToUse
    {
        get { return buttonMarginToUse; }
        set
        {
            buttonMarginToUse = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonMarginToUse));
        }
    }
```

The mainwindow view sets the datacontext of the mainwindowviewmodel

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(model);
        DataContext = viewModel;

        SourceInitialized += Window1_SourceInitialized;
    }
```

I genuinely can't understand what is wrong - there is no binding error, but since shifting my code from viewmodel to usercontrol (was trying to abstract as much as i can from vm) things are not working properly...

Comment: **"viewmodel that is creating an instance of the usercontrol"** - this is generally wrong according to MVVM. A viewmodel must not create any UI items (user controls). Consider re-designing your approach.

Comment: So how can I get my viewmodel to interact with my usercontrol then? i.e. who should be creating the instance of the usercontrol? None of my buttons icommands are triggering on the usercontrol from the viewmodel so i suspect something is wrong even though the bindings are not complaining

Comment: the viewmodel has to set properties of the usercontrol... so not sure how to go about this

Comment: These are the basic things of MVVM. The viewmodel interacts with its view via data bindings and events. The instances of the view should be created by the framework (WPF) via data templating, styling and content templating. The view instances may also be created by services (like navigation service, user interaction service, etc), but not by viewmodels.

Comment: So if I were to create the usercontrol in the view, how would I do that? As you can see above, I already have <views:WellPlateSelectorUC x:Name="wellPlateUC" DataContext="{Binding WellPlateSelectorUCViewModel}" />, do I need to change the XAML in order for it to generate the usercontrol programmatically? Then would I need to fire off events for the view (viewmodel) to interact with the usercontrol? i'm struggling to picture it in my head

Comment: I would suggest you to grab a good WPF/MVVM book and to read it carefully. It's a broad topic and it can't be explained in a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I added `            <DataTemplate x:Key="UC">
                <views:SelectorUC/>
            </DataTemplate>` to my view XAML, i'll figure out where to go from there, i'm sure i'm on the right track!!!

Comment: oh i think you forgot to mention, key thing i'm doing wrong - linking a vm and uc to one single view. That is not possible I have now found out